# Homomorphisms : If $\ker\beta \subseteq \ker\alpha$ and $\beta$ is onto then $\alpha = \gamma \circ \beta$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

> Let $\alpha : A \to B$ and $\beta : A \to C$ be homomorphisms with $\beta$ onto and $\ker\beta \subseteq \ker\alpha$. Show there is a homomorphism $\gamma : C \to B$ such that $\alpha = \gamma \circ \beta$.

It seems that I need to use the first and second isomorphism theorems. By the first isomorphism theorem I get that:

By $\beta$ onto I get an isomorphism from $A/\ker\beta$ to $C$

and from the second isomorphism theorem I get that :

by $\ker\beta \subseteq \ker\alpha $ we get $A/\ker\alpha \simeq (A/\ker\beta)\Big / (\ker\alpha \, / \ker\beta) $

I am not sure how to piece these together to get this $\gamma$.

Comment: Homomorphisms... **of what** ? Groups, rings, algebras, linear spaces,...? Very probably these are abelian groups and you're about to work with exact sequences, split short sequences and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio, why does it matter?

Comment: @Hubble I think it does, as the OP may have a definite goal to achieve, as I wrote in the last part of my comment.

Comment: From a universal property, you get a homomorphism $\overline{\alpha} \colon A/\ker \beta \to B$ such that $\alpha = \overline{\alpha} \circ \pi$, where $\pi \colon A \to A/\ker \beta$ is the canonical map.

Comment: @DonAntonio It is universal algebra, all that matters is that $A,B,C$ are similar algebras, so doesn't really matter in the context of the problem what algebras they are

Comment: Does $\ker \alpha$ represent a congruence (rather than a kernel in the sense of say monodies)?

Comment: Via the first isomorphism you obtain $A/\ker\alpha \simeq C/\delta$ with  $\delta\in \mathop{Con} C$ corresponding to $\ker\alpha / \ker\beta$. But $A/\ker\alpha \simeq \alpha[A]$ canonically. So you can take a path like $C \to C/\delta \to A/\ker\alpha \to B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than thinking, "Which theorems should I use to prove this?", I want to ask instead, "What could this map $\gamma:C \longrightarrow B$ possibly be?"  To that end, suppose $c$ is in $C$.  How can we map $c$ over to $B$?  Well, the only way we know of getting anything into $B$ is the map $\alpha:A \longrightarrow B$, but $c$ isn't in $A$.  Ah, but $\beta$ is surjective, so $c$ has a pre-image (at least one) in $A$.  Alright, let's take $a$ to be a pre-image of $c$, so that $\beta(a) = c$.  Maybe we can define $\gamma(c) = \alpha(a)$.  Does this yield a well-defined map?

The main issue is this: If $c$ has more than one pre-image under $\beta$, might $\alpha$ send them to distinct points in $B$?  If so, then we're sunk; at least, we'll have have to find a different approach.  To find out, let $a$ and $a'$ both be pre-images of $c$.  We need to show that $\alpha(a) = \alpha(a')$.  But ${\rm ker}(\beta) \subset {\rm ker}(\alpha)$, which implies that $\alpha(x) = \alpha(y)$ whenever $\beta(x) = \beta(y)$.  Since $\beta(a) = \beta(a')$, it follows that $\alpha(a) = \alpha(a')$, implying that our $\gamma$ is a well-defined function (of sets).  And since $\alpha$ is a morphism, it follows that $\gamma$ is as well.

finally, does $\alpha = \gamma \circ \beta$?  Yes, essentially by definition: Since $a$ is itself a pre-image of $\beta(a)$, our definition of $\gamma$ implies that, for all $a \in A$, $\gamma(\beta(a)) = \alpha(a)$.